# Class weights not working with return_sequences Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

''''
#x_train format = [samples, timesteps, features]
#y_train format = [samples, timesteps]

```
num_timesteps = len(x_train[0])
num_features = len(x_train[0, 0])
num_classes = 3

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape = (num_timesteps, num_features)))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], 
sample_weight_mode='temporal')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=500, class_weight = class_weights)
```

''''

I get an error that seems to indicate something is wrong with indices. The code works if I remove class_weights.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Documents/Neural Network for probabilities/keras_test_real_data_non_stateful_return_sequences_with_class_weights.py", line 129, in 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=500, class_weight = class_weights)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 848, in fit
tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in **call**
result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 644, in _call
return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2420, in **call**
return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1665, in _filtered_call
self.captured_inputs)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1746, in _call_flat
ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 598, in call
ctx=ctx)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  indices[1] = 4 is not in [0, 3)
[[{{node GatherV2}}]]
[[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4037]

Function call stack:
train_function

Comment: how are you setting class weights? something like, class_weight = {0: 1.,
                1: 3.,
                2: 2.}?

Comment: @V.M exactly that. I forgot to include it sorry